# How do I store data in char arrays and convert to int in C

Tags: c

So I currently take a file pointer as a parameter as im reading data in a file stored as `14 00 05` where `14` is the hours `00` is the minutes and `05` is the seconds. I want to be able to convert these values to into a single int and produce the output `int time = 140005`

```
int time_conversion(FILE *file) {
    char hrs[2];
    char mins[2];
    char secs[2];
    char total[6];

    fscanf(file, " %s %s %s", hrs, mins, secs);
    strcat(total, hrs);
    strcat(total, mins);
    strcat(total, secs);
    return atoi(total);
}
```

The issue I'm currently having is that when I read in the `char mins[2]` the first char stored in `char hrs[2]` gets ovverun for some unkown reason.
Example of output after the `fprintf()`

```
char hrs[0] = '\000'
char hrs[1] = '4'

char mins[0] = '\000'
char mins[1] = '0'

char secs[0] = '0'
char secs[1] = '5'
```

Comment: Your arrays are too short and will overflow, causing data corruption or worse. Make them `[100]` until you get the code working, then establish how they can be adjusted. And please note that the first `strcat(total, hrs);` should be `strcpy(total, hrs);` since trying to concatenate to an *uninitialised variable* is undefined behaviour.

Comment: Just remember: `char` strings in `C` need a null-terminator (which is itself a `char`).

Comment: You're working with strings, concatenating them, and calling `atoi`.  Another way (not saying it's better or worse, just different) would be to scan `hrs`, `min`, and `secs` as ints using `%d`, and compute `10000*hrs + 100*mins + secs`.  (Or for a more compact representation, `3600*hrs + 60*mins + secs`.)

Comment: @SteveSummit Thank You for literally saving me hours of work! I've spent ages looking at this trying to figure out the solution. What do I do however if I want to add a leading zero because sometimes the input is ```1 15 23``` and the output should be ```011523```

Comment: Is your original input guaranteed to have leading 0's, or not?  (Your question suggests that's not guaranteed.)  The answer depends in part upon your final output format.  If your final output format is `int`, there's no difference between `11523` and `011523`; there's basically no way to have a leading 0.  If your final output format is string, you can add calls to `sprintf` somewhere, with formats like `%02d` (for individual hours, minutes, or seconds values), or `%06d` (for the whole shebang).

Comment: If your original input is not guaranteed to have leading 0's, the use-strings-and-`strcat` approach is doomed to failure whenever minutes or seconds are less than 10.

Comment: At any rate, to get leading 0's with MerMonkey's answer, use `printf("%06d", wynik)` in `main()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do it with strings:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int time_conversion(FILE* file) {
    char hrs[3];
    char mins[3];
    char secs[3];
    char total[7];
    fscanf(file, "%s %s %s", hrs, mins, secs);
    strcpy(total, hrs);
    strcat(total, mins);
    strcat(total, secs);
    return atoi(total);
}
int main(void) {
    FILE* f = fopen("file.txt", "r");
    int wynik = time_conversion(f);
    printf("%d", wynik);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: When you are working with strings remember that 14 is really '1' '4' '\0' so it needs 3 array size

Comment: Per a comment on the original question, there's a pretty big problem here if the input is something like `1 2 3`.

Comment: Also, if you're going to use needlessly tiny arrays like `char hrs[3];`, you really need to protect them by using `%2s` in the `fscanf` call.  (And of course this advice holds almost equally well even when the arrays are not tiny.)